# Question about maximum and minimum of a function of C^(k+1)

Tags: derivatives

Question states:
"Let $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ b of class $C^{k+1}$. Suppose $f^{(j)}(a) = 0$ for $0 \leq j < k$ and  $f^{(k)}(a) \neq 0$. If $k$ is even, show that $f$ has a maximum or minimum at $a$ depending on the sign of $f^{(k)}(a)$. What if $k$ is odd?"

I believe that I can solve this problem using induction and Second Derivative Test. (Please tell me that this is the right approach or if there are other theorems I need to use). When I tried to prove it, however, I couldn't really make the distinction between when $k$ is odd and $k$ is even. Does the result hold for both? If not, could you provide me with counterexample or proof that the result don't hold when $k$ is odd?

Comment: hint: compare "$k+1$ is odd" to "$1=1+0$" and "$k+1$ is even" to "$2=1+1$ with $f^{1}(a)\neq 0$".

Comment: Hint: look at some simple functions, like $f(x) = x^n$.

Comment: Oh thanks user 2512357. So if we just look at the function $f(x) = x$, $f(0) = 0$ but $f'(0) = 1$ but 0 is neither maximum nor minimum. Right?

Comment: @S.RH for example